# Can I end all httpd processes? (OSX, 10.7.4, Lion)

Tags: macos, osx-lion, httpd

I have several instances of `httpd` running on my Mac. Don't need to run a web server, would like to end them all, as they add up to about 100mb of unnessecary RAM. What is the configuration that sets them to run? How can I disable it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Mountain Lion removed the Web Sharing option, maybe you upgraded and had it running some time in the past?  Anyway, you'll need to open Terminal for this:

```
sudo killall httpd
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

The first will fail if you've already killed all the processes, the second disables startup.

Comment: He's on 10.7.4 according to the Q.

Comment: Fair, but in the future as more users come back to this same question they may be on 10.8 (or later) so overtime this is a more relevant answer.

Comment: This solved it for me on 10.7.5; even though Web Sharing exists and is unchecked in System Preferences, `httpd` was surviving/respawning through `killall` until using this `launchctl` command (but this particular system might have other issues)

Comment: Wow! I was getting this error with MAMP Pro, and running the above fixed it. https://cl.ly/010Y2g2V3v3M/Image%202017-01-23%20at%201.35.59%20PM.png

Answer (score 3):

Open the *Sharing* preference pane in *System Preferences* and uncheck *Web Sharing*.

Comment: FWIW, this option has been removed from Mountain Lion.

Comment: nope still running httpd on my lion

Answer (score 0):

`sudo kill -9 [PID]` and entering the process ID for PID ends any process. This can kill httpd . Now, you want to remove httpd form startup since you dont use it anyway.
Go to:

Library/LaunchAgents

Library/LaunchDaemons

Library/StartupItems

and remove httpd from these locations. This will stop it from ever running again. You can keep a backup though just in case you want the Apache web server in the future.

Comment: So why the downvote? This method works... not something hard.You can just google this

Comment: httpd is normally started by /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist, and changing the contents of /System is not recommended. Using launchctl to manage it (as @Jeff recommended) is a much better way to do it.